# Read the displayed cell value not the entire value produced form the formula

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to write a macro for excel which compares values across different workbooks/worksheets. The problem that I am currently facing is that when the macro looks at the first cell in the sheet being transcription checked it will take the value which is derived from the formula in said cell (a long number), not the value of the cell its self (a number rounded to 4dp). This is the part of VBA code that does the transcription checking:

```
For cCol = fCol To lCol
    For cRow = fRow To lRow
        If ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(ShName).Cells(cRow, cCol).Value = RefWB.Worksheets(RefShName).Cells(cRow + rowOS, cCol + colOS).Value Then
            Else
            
            If ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(ShName).Cells(cRow, cCol).Value = "" Then
                ShVal = "Blank cell"
                Else
                ShVal = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(ShName).Cells(cRow, cCol)
            End If
            
            Debug.Print "Trx error: (" & ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(ShName).Cells(cRow, cCol).Address & ") This sheet value = " & ShVal & _
            ", reference sheet (" & RefWB.Worksheets(RefShName).Cells(cRow + rowOS, cCol + colOS).Address; "" _
            & ") = " & RefWB.Worksheets(RefShName).Cells(cRow + rowOS, cCol + colOS)
            TrxTotCount = TrxTotCount + 1
        End If
    Next cRow
Next cCol
```

The formula in the cells are =IF(COUNT(INDEX('Master Calibration File'!$F:$F,MATCH('Peak Areas'!$F$3:$F$3,'Master Calibration File'!$B:$B,0)))<1, "", INDEX('Master Calibration File'!$F:$F,MATCH('Peak Areas'!$F$3:$F$3,'Master Calibration File'!$B:$B,0))). Though this will point to different columns depending on the cell - in excel these values are calculated from imported data which has around 10-15 dps before being rounded to a 4dp number.

When I run the macro I get an output like this:
Trx error: ($H$70) This sheet value = 0.960209783279582, reference sheet ($H$66) = 0.96
Trx error: ($H$71) This sheet value = 0.983517929757312, reference sheet ($H$67) = 0.98

How can I change the VBA code to only look at the value displayed in the cell not the whole value before rounding? note, not all values will be rounded to 4dp.

Comment: `RefWB.Worksheets(RefShName).Cells(cRow + rowOS, cCol + colOS).Text` gives the as-displayed value

Comment: This worked perfectly, thank you!!